# Looking for raw interferogram data / raw FID data from FT-IR / FT-NIR / FT-NMR

Tags: spectroscopy, mass-spectrometry

I'm trying to get my hands on some raw interferogram data / raw FID data from an FT-IR / FT-NIR / FT-NMR so I can run some tests using FFT with it (it needs to be real data). Here's a picture below of the data I'm looking for **highlighted in yellow**.  I'm looking for Alkali metals (Sodium, Potassium, but also Magnesium, Gold, Silver, Platinum and Palladium).  Any ideas where I can get these or if someone can send them to me as a text/data file?  I've searched NIST but everything is already converted

[image]

Comment: I think I may have a HCl-DCl FTIR. Let me check and I'll get back to you.

Comment: I don't unserstand if [these](http://www.epa.gov/ttnemc01/ftir/ignam.html) are FT-IR spectra maybe take a look..

Comment: @GM - Those indeed are interferograms of a variety of organic compounds. RickT - I'm uncertain if the metals you list will have meaningful data using these techniques. For example, IR spectroscopy is all about the vibrations of covalent bonds. In order for a vibration to be IR active, it needs to be symmetry-allowed (usually by experiencing a change in dipole).

Answer (score 1):

In *The Journal of Chemical Education*, published by the American Chemical Society, a rather recent [article](http://pubs.acs.org/doi/pdf/10.1021/ed300787v) presented a related project, hosted by the University of Minnesota.  Intentionally it is about raw FIDs-as-obtained, out of the NMR spectrometer, aiming to teach correct data processing (including spectra with two orthogonal frequency scales). The article is sponsored by the authors (i.e. freely accessible), the database requires an e-mail to register. 
 Reference: J. Chem. Educ., 2013, 90 (7), pp 941–943; DOI: 10.1021/ed300787v